# jQuery to remove from the DOM more than one occurence of an element

Tags: jquery

Here in this piece of Jquery I am showing active_user_table at the same place where earlier reg_user_table was displayed. So first I am making reg_user_table display none and next I setting active_user_display as block. Afterwards I am issuing getJSON which is working fine. Problem is when the table is attached and when I want to attach the class active_table on all tables so that I could count all the tables and allow only one of it to be seen and remove or detach the others from DOM. I am not able to do so the class active_table is applied to all but the last one. The recently added is not showing the class active_table.

```
 $('#reg_user_table').hide();
 if($('#active_user_table').is(':hidden')){   
     $('#active_user_table').css("display","block");
     $.getJSON("/siteadmin/active_user_count", function(response_data)
     { 
         var data = [response_data.today,response_data.Sevendays,response_data.Month];
         var caption = ['Active Today','Active Past 7 Days','Active This Month'];
         var $table = $('<table/>'); 

         for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) { 
             $table.append('<tr><td><h3>'+caption[i]+':'+'</h3></td><td><h3>'+ data[i] + '</h3></td></tr>');
         } 
         $('#active_user_table').append($table);
     });

     $('#active_user_table').children().addClass("active_table");
     console.log("Hello World!" + $('.active_table').length); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to async world. Your `$.getJSON` is executed after the last two lines.

Comment: Thanks to soyuka also for taking time to edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to async world. Your `$.getJSON` is executed after the last two lines.
Put them inside the sucsess callback

```
$.getJSON("/siteadmin/active_user_count", function (response_data) {
    //...
    $('#active_user_table').append($table);

    // put it here....  
    $('#active_user_table').children().addClass("active_table");
    console.log("Hello World!" + $('.active_table').length);
});
```

Comment: Oh Oh This was silly of me but thanks to you,you have fixed it.You diagnosis is perfect, kidwon hats off to you!!

I am accepting you answer. One more thing, this same goes for all the other jQuery ajax functions.

Comment: No big deal, that is essentially to javascript world :) You'll deal with asynchronous calls quite a lot in future, there's no escape.

Comment: So this will be true for all the different variants of ajax call.

Comment: yep, indeed it is. It's just not efficient to stop code executing and wait for data retrieval, that's why it is an event driven pattern.

Comment: Tremendous!!. Can you please refer me to any source having more details on this particular thing.